# How to get a perfectly centered element (which is surrounded by two independent elements) within an absolutely positioned window-centered container?

Tags: html, css

I have a markup that should look like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
  It is the primary text.
  </div>
  <div id="center">
  Hi!
  </div>
  <div id="right">
  some content 
  </div>      
</div>
```

The block-level `#container` element should be absolutely positioned and perfectly centered by the width (not by the height!) of the entire browser window:

```
#container {
  display: block;
  width: 95vw;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
}
```

The block-level `#center` element will have no predefined width or height, its dimensions are unpredictable and it should take as much space as it is needed (but maybe it will have predefined `max-height`/`max-width` value). **EDIT** / Clarification: it should take **minimal** required width/height, which means that it will take 20 pixels for padding, and some small amount of pixels for "Hi!", and nothing more, so in this case, it will be very small relatively to the container.

```
#center {
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The block-level `#left` element should take **all possible remaining space of the #container**, and it will also have `text-overflow: ellipsis` property:

```
#left {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The `#right` element should take **all possible remaining space of the #container**. It has no special properties, but it is just an independent block-level element which can contain anything.

```
#right {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The result should look like this (in the example below, it is assumed that there is no space to contain the `"ext."` substring of the `#left` element, and it is replaced with an ellipsis):

```
--------------------------WINDOW EDGE--------------------------
|                              |                              |
|                              |                              |
W                           (75 px)                           W
I                              |                              I
N                              |                              N
D +—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————+ D
O |  It is the primary t...|  Hi!  |some content            | O
W +—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————+ W
  <- - - - - - - - - - - - -(95 vw)- - - - - - - - - - - - ->
E                                                             E
D                                                             D
G                                                             G
E                                                             E
```

Note that distances between left/right borders of `#container` and left/right edges of the window should be equal: `(100vw - 95vw)/2 = 2.5vw`.
How to achieve this? I have read all possible explanations of how to center an element, but cannot find the answer to this specific problem... All I see is to apply predefined dimensions to each element, and then aplly the absolute positioning to each element independently... which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `display:flexbox;` to create a "*perfect center divs*".

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  width: 95vw;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin:auto;
}

#center {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
  animation: center;
  width:auto;
}

#left {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 35%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 35%;
}
```

Note here: you need to defined #left and #right width equally to make it perfectly center.

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/usytj8gm/3/

Comment: Please, read the edited question. In this demo, the width of `#center` is too big and don't match to what I described. Moreover, I mentioned that `#container` should be centered **by the width** of the window. The distance from the top edge of the window is `75px`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/usytj8gm/2/ . You mean like this? Now #center div is minimal width. and #left, #right filled remaining space

Comment: Now `#container` has a right distance from the top of the window, but in Firefox, I see that is not centered by the window's width at all.

Comment: `left: 0; right: 0; margin:auto;` You need this for center #container in windows. Sorry. I forgot to save it. https://jsfiddle.net/usytj8gm/3/

Comment: `width:35%` means they have a same width at first so when set `flex-grow:1`.  Both of their width grow equally. Without set width of #left and #right, browser will grow their width to fit their  inner content. And i dont think there's a pure css workaround without flexbox since you want #left and #right fill all remaining space

Comment: And can this problem be solved without using `display: inline-block`, assuming that all elements have `display: block`? Just interesting...

Comment: Just tested it out. It still works. i think when `.container` set `display:flex;` then all children elements have same display propery, something like `flex-item`.